# Swift - Asynchronous wait failed: Exceeded timeout of 20 seconds, with unfulfilled expectations: "myExpectation"

Tags: swift, unit-testing

Here is the code of test function:

```
   func testGetDataFromURL()  {

    var exp = self.expectation(description: "myExpectation")
    exp.expectedFulfillmentCount = 3
    self.objImpleTest.letsCheckReqAndRes()
    exp.fulfill()

   waitForExpectations(timeout: 20) { (error) in
        XCTAssertNil(error, "Test timed out. \ 
 (error?.localizedDescription)")

        print("X: async expectation")
    }
}
```

Here is the code of main function:

```
func letsCheckReqAndRes() {
    var gotResults: String = ""

    //var results: String = ""

    let headers = [
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "Postman-Token": "0d2eb1be-fb26-4425-b6b1-f1fa37005cee"
    ]

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: 
  "http://www.mocky.io/v2/5a964d253200006e005e2d50")! as URL,
                                      cachePolicy: 
 .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                      timeoutInterval: 10.0)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
    let session = URLSession.shared

    self.delegate?.notGotAnything(nothingReceived: "Checking Condition 
   But not sure what it will receive??")

    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, 
   completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        print("\(response)")
       print("\(data)")
        if (error != nil) {
            print(error)
            self.delegate?.serviceFailed(error: error.debugDescription)
            return

        } else {
            let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse

            print(httpResponse)

            let parsedData = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: 
  data!) as! [String:Any]
            let objData = parsedData!["data"] as! [String:Any]

            gotResults = "\(objData)"

            var getActualVal :Bool = false

           self.delegate?.showResults(data: gotResults)

           print (getActualVal)

        }
    })

     dataTask.resume()
}
```

Here is the log:

```
 Asynchronous wait failed: Exceeded timeout of 20 seconds, with 
unfulfilled expectations: "myExpectation".
```

/Users/amitsaxena/Desktop/ProjectsiOS/RESTServiceExample/RESTServiceExample/RESTServiceExampleBasicUnitTests.swift:69: error: -[RESTServiceExampleBasicUnitTests.RESTServiceExampleBasicUnitTests testGetDataFromURL] : XCTAssertNil failed: "Error Domain=com.apple.XCTestErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)"" - Test timed out. Optional("The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.XCTestErrorDomain error 0.)")
X: async expectation

Comment: Why are you setting `exp.expectedFulfillmentCount` to 3? As this will mean you have to call `exp.fullfill()` 3 times? [Taken from here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestexpectation/2806572-expectedfulfillmentcount)

Comment: Yes, actually if I not adding count by 3 then it pass the test but does not complete response as requred and does not go to my delegate function but after giving count it gets responses normally and goes into required delegate methods but then in last throws the error as mentioned in problem so giving count resolved my problem of handling responses, please advise

Comment: That is because usually you are meant to call `exp.fullfill()` inside a callback after an asynchronous method, however it can be achieved the way you wish by using [this](https://savvyapps.com/blog/ios-expectations-test-async-functions-without-callback-method)

Comment: Thanks Mr. Wright, I followed article and tried to put my expect.fulfill() inside dispatch queue block but still no luck and it gets failed